# Broadcast[UDP] sendto Error on Mac (Code works in Win fine!)

Tags: macos, c++11, broadcast

i have a Problem with a Broadcast on MAC using c++ 11

The Code works fine in Windows but on Mac i get a -1 back from my sendto function, maybe u see my error.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    SOCKET s;
#endif
    int recSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    int askSinlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    ssize_t askBuflen = MAXBUF;
    int recCheckCall;
#ifdef _WIN32
    int clientLength;
#elif __APPLE__
    socklen_t clientLength;
#endif
    int message;

    char buf[512];
    char askStatus;
    char status;
    char askBuffer[MAXBUF];
    struct sockaddr_in sock_in, server_adress, client_adress, client_adress2;
    char askYes = 1;
    DEBUG_LOG(35, "Im Boradcast");
#ifdef _WIN32
    WSADATA w;
    if (int result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &w) != 0)                                               // Zugriff auf Winsock Libary
    {
        DEBUG_LOG(300, "WSA Startup failed");

        return -1;
    }
#endif

    recSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (recSocket == -1)
    {
        DEBUG_LOG(301, "Receive Socket Error");
#ifdef _WIN32
        closesocket(recSocket);
#elif __APPLE__
        close(recSocket);
#endif
        return -2;
    }

    sock_in.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    sock_in.sin_port = htons(4028);
    sock_in.sin_family = PF_INET;

    client_adress.sin_family = PF_INET;
    client_adress.sin_port = htons(4029);
    client_adress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(-1);

    status = bind(recSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&sock_in, askSinlen);

    if (status == -1)
    {
        DEBUG_LOG(302, "Fehler beim binden des Sockets");
#ifdef _WIN32
        closesocket(recSocket);
#elif __APPLE__
        close(recSocket);
#endif
        return -3;
    }
    status = setsockopt(recSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &askYes, sizeof(askYes));

    sprintf(askBuffer, "Ciao");
    askBuflen = strlen(askBuffer);
    status = sendto(recSocket, askBuffer, askBuflen, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_adress, sizeof(client_adress));
    if (status < 0)
    {
        DEBUG_LOG(status, "Fehler ist: ");
        DEBUG_LOG(303, "Fehler beim senden des Broadcastes");
#ifdef _WIN32
        closesocket(recSocket);
#elif __APPLE__
        close(recSocket);
#endif
        return -4;
    }
```

It would be great if u could help me, i think its just a small bug wich i didnt see...

Have a nice day

Kindly Regards

Comment: What is the value of errno after sendto fails?

Comment: errno?
Errorcode from sendto is -1, but whats is errno?

Comment: osx is a posix system.  Best to program to posix rather than osx specifics (it simplifies porting to other posix systems like Linux).  Edit (to add the important bit).  sendto spec:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sendto.html
errno spec: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/errno.html